# Can't ping EC2 instance after enabling ICMP packets

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, ping, icmp, security-groups

I followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance) to allow me to ping my EC2 instance. In my security group I have Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4, Echo Reply, N/A, Anywhere.

However it simply doesn't work. If i run ping ec2-X-X-X-X.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com, or if I run ping X.X.X.X, it simply hangs forever. How to fix this?

My VPC settings are all default. The subnet route table has an internet gateway enabled and Network ACL allows all traffic in and out.

Answer (score 9):

Allowing ICMP Echo Request as well in the security groups fixed it.

Comment: You don't need inbound Echo Reply at all -- just Echo Request.